# Import georeferenced dwg-files to SketchUP

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, dxf, dwg, sketchup

I have a georeferenced DWG-file in a national projection and want to import it into SketchUp pro 2015 without loosing the georeference. My workflow so far was to import it into QGIS, check it's location using OpenLayers and save it again with the projection EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator), open a new SketchUP-file, set the geo location for the project and import the DWG file. This dosn't work.

The DWG import is placed somewhere. I don't want to georeference it again with the Google image, because this would cause a big lack in precision.

Does anyone know a solution, maybe a file format that works, or any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SketchUp is not losing the georeference, you can import, edit and export a model and it will keep its position. Even if you work within a national georeference system. It is not necessary and maybe harmful if you define the location for your project.

There is a setting in the import options to keep the original point of origin that has to be set.